# Heroku application error when deploying app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment

I am doing my first deployment to Heroku and I have an Application Error. It reads

> An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

I have added the `pg` to gemfile and followed the setup for puma web server.

Does someone know how I can fix this? I've looked around and read other posts but none of those solutions seem to be able to fix what's going on with me.

```
2015-06-23T06:08:05.135418+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bin/rails: No such file or directory
2015-06-23T06:08:05.857563+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-06-23T06:08:05.845406+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2015-06-23T07:39:56.871349+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-06-23T07:40:07.045897+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 52445 -e production`
2015-06-23T07:40:09.416565+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-06-23T07:40:09.406842+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2015-06-23T07:40:08.580332+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bin/rails: No such file or directory
2015-06-23T11:06:31.005547+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-06-23T11:06:40.489918+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 45824 -e production`
2015-06-23T11:06:41.944126+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bin/rails: No such file or directory
2015-06-23T11:06:42.728921+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-06-23T11:06:42.716580+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2015-06-23T19:27:47.611339+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/robots.txt" host=areyoutaken.herokuapp.com request_id=1c5dc120-24d1-4823-9283-3c396d899d41 fwd="157.55.39.235" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-06-23T19:27:56.576248+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=areyoutaken.herokuapp.com request_id=ffe06a2f-7fe2-4dd9-8fac-199aa9ce48b0 fwd="157.55.39.235" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-06-23T19:47:05.610561+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=areyoutaken.herokuapp.com request_id=38597d3a-750c-4ff4-8384-67de523c6226 fwd="73.54.214.248" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-06-24T03:34:44.769597+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=areyoutaken.herokuapp.com request_id=855033cb-e6db-4a3d-9346-f7a6ef7b7a28 fwd="73.54.214.248" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-06-24T03:34:47.517061+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=areyoutaken.herokuapp.com request_id=e99f4acd-fed1-4b8f-9037-94747cbc567b fwd="73.54.214.248" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-06-24T03:43:15.864729+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `false && AUTOMATED DIAGNOSIS BEING RUN BY HEROKU SUPPORT; cat Procfile` by 
2015-06-24T03:43:25.864817+00:00 heroku[run.4070]: Awaiting client
2015-06-24T03:43:25.891312+00:00 heroku[run.4070]: Starting process with command `false && AUTOMATED DIAGNOSIS BEING RUN BY HEROKU SUPPORT; cat Procfile`
2015-06-24T03:43:26.288537+00:00 heroku[run.4070]: State changed from starting to up
2015-06-24T03:43:27.558053+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `false && AUTOMATED DIAGNOSIS BEING RUN BY HEROKU SUPPORT; cat Gemfile` by
2015-06-24T03:43:28.191980+00:00 heroku[run.4070]: Process exited with status 1
2015-06-24T03:43:28.214454+00:00 heroku[run.4070]: State changed from up to complete
2015-06-24T03:43:37.193534+00:00 heroku[run.2198]: Starting process with command `false && AUTOMATED DIAGNOSIS BEING RUN BY HEROKU SUPPORT; cat Gemfile`
2015-06-24T03:43:37.159595+00:00 heroku[run.2198]: Awaiting client
2015-06-24T03:43:37.655722+00:00 heroku[run.2198]: State changed from starting to up
2015-06-24T03:43:38.924101+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `false && AUTOMATED DIAGNOSIS BEING RUN BY HEROKU SUPPORT; cat Gemfile.lock` by 
2015-06-24T03:43:39.577465+00:00 heroku[run.2198]: Process exited with status 0
2015-06-24T03:43:39.584141+00:00 heroku[run.2198]: State changed from up to complete
2015-06-24T03:43:48.245771+00:00 heroku[run.5907]: Awaiting client
2015-06-24T03:43:48.289767+00:00 heroku[run.5907]: Starting process with command `false && AUTOMATED DIAGNOSIS BEING RUN BY HEROKU SUPPORT; cat Gemfile.lock`
2015-06-24T03:43:48.504068+00:00 heroku[run.5907]: State changed from starting to up
2015-06-24T03:43:49.678442+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `false && AUTOMATED DIAGNOSIS BEING RUN BY HEROKU SUPPORT; cat config/unicorn.rb` by 
2015-06-24T03:43:50.294772+00:00 heroku[run.5907]: State changed from up to complete
2015-06-24T03:43:50.260085+00:00 heroku[run.5907]: Process exited with status 0
2015-06-24T03:43:58.833931+00:00 heroku[run.9140]: Awaiting client
2015-06-24T03:43:58.873519+00:00 heroku[run.9140]: Starting process with command `false && AUTOMATED DIAGNOSIS BEING RUN BY HEROKU SUPPORT; cat config/unicorn.rb`
2015-06-24T03:43:59.122398+00:00 heroku[run.9140]: State changed from starting to up
2015-06-24T03:44:00.508136+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `false && AUTOMATED DIAGNOSIS BEING RUN BY HEROKU SUPPORT; cat config/puma.rb` by  
2015-06-24T03:44:01.467150+00:00 heroku[run.9140]: Process exited with status 1
2015-06-24T03:44:01.478969+00:00 heroku[run.9140]: State changed from up to complete
2015-06-24T03:44:20.474134+00:00 heroku[run.8902]: Awaiting client
2015-06-24T03:44:20.555661+00:00 heroku[run.8902]: Starting process with command `false && AUTOMATED DIAGNOSIS BEING RUN BY HEROKU SUPPORT; cat config/puma.rb`
2015-06-24T03:44:20.712591+00:00 heroku[run.8902]: State changed from starting to up
2015-06-24T03:44:22.491184+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `false && AUTOMATED DIAGNOSIS BEING RUN BY HEROKU SUPPORT; cat config/initializers/timeout.rb` by  
2015-06-24T03:44:23.203713+00:00 heroku[run.8902]: Process exited with status 1
2015-06-24T03:44:23.233656+00:00 heroku[run.8902]: State changed from up to complete
2015-06-24T03:44:32.457146+00:00 heroku[run.9448]: Awaiting client
2015-06-24T03:44:32.507243+00:00 heroku[run.9448]: Starting process with command `false && AUTOMATED DIAGNOSIS BEING RUN BY HEROKU SUPPORT; cat config/initializers/timeout.rb`
2015-06-24T03:44:32.756976+00:00 heroku[run.9448]: State changed from starting to up
2015-06-24T03:44:34.110457+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `false && AUTOMATED DIAGNOSIS BEING RUN BY HEROKU SUPPORT; cat config/initializers/database_connection.rb` by  
2015-06-24T03:44:34.809918+00:00 heroku[run.9448]: State changed from up to complete
2015-06-24T03:44:34.793131+00:00 heroku[run.9448]: Process exited with status 1
2015-06-24T03:44:44.529225+00:00 heroku[run.2356]: Awaiting client
2015-06-24T03:44:44.556511+00:00 heroku[run.2356]: Starting process with command `false && AUTOMATED DIAGNOSIS BEING RUN BY HEROKU SUPPORT; cat config/initializers/database_connection.rb`
2015-06-24T03:44:44.822631+00:00 heroku[run.2356]: State changed from starting to up
2015-06-24T03:44:46.004603+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `false && AUTOMATED DIAGNOSIS BEING RUN BY HEROKU SUPPORT; cat config/environments/production.rb` by  
2015-06-24T03:44:46.603524+00:00 heroku[run.2356]: Process exited with status 1
2015-06-24T03:44:46.597452+00:00 heroku[run.2356]: State changed from up to complete
2015-06-24T03:44:54.417247+00:00 heroku[run.7130]: Awaiting client
2015-06-24T03:44:54.475518+00:00 heroku[run.7130]: Starting process with command `false && AUTOMATED DIAGNOSIS BEING RUN BY HEROKU SUPPORT; cat config/environments/production.rb`
2015-06-24T03:44:54.774410+00:00 heroku[run.7130]: State changed from starting to up
2015-06-24T03:44:56.747720+00:00 heroku[run.7130]: Process exited with status 0
2015-06-24T03:44:56.759805+00:00 heroku[run.7130]: State changed from up to complete
2015-06-24T09:30:26.772688+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-06-24T09:30:37.719614+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 56552 -e production`
2015-06-24T09:30:39.822774+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bin/rails: No such file or directory
2015-06-24T09:30:40.715770+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-06-24T09:30:40.694675+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2015-06-24T12:58:54.912618+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/robots.txt" host=areyoutaken.herokuapp.com request_id=586e8274-8b09-4fa7-922b-de3dbaac1ce7 fwd="157.55.39.153" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-06-24T12:59:09.862623+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=areyoutaken.herokuapp.com request_id=2d1999bb-cf85-40af-b477-8c05dcca74a9 fwd="157.55.39.154" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-06-24T14:13:48.499735+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=areyoutaken.herokuapp.com request_id=c0e307ba-f974-4834-b4f8-ab50c4f8c52a fwd="207.46.13.64" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-06-24T14:48:17.955631+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=areyoutaken.herokuapp.com request_id=c3815567-dafa-4524-b82c-3663b18cbb54 fwd="157.55.39.78" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-06-24T15:27:49.824212+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=areyoutaken.herokuapp.com request_id=b56c868b-9733-42d8-a654-64f688297124 fwd="157.55.39.78" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-06-24T16:41:13.827034+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=areyoutaken.herokuapp.com request_id=eab5322d-303d-4ba3-843c-855676ab8d19 fwd="157.55.39.154" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-06-24T18:21:42.899175+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=areyoutaken.herokuapp.com request_id=d8f211e6-2d7a-4d24-b6f1-a75e121ba8e6 fwd="157.55.39.5" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-06-24T21:18:51.904467+00:00 heroku[api]: Set MAX_THREADS config vars by  
2015-06-24T21:18:51.904467+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v6 created by  
2015-06-24T21:18:52.025225+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-06-24T21:19:02.708240+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 55492 -e production`
2015-06-24T21:19:04.412120+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bin/rails: No such file or directory
2015-06-24T21:19:05.233124+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-06-24T21:19:05.234307+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-06-24T21:19:05.221340+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2015-06-24T21:19:12.614653+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 44814 -e production`
2015-06-24T21:19:15.139278+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bin/rails: No such file or directory
2015-06-24T21:19:15.849254+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2015-06-24T21:19:15.868089+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-06-24T21:20:22.629350+00:00 heroku[api]: Set MIN_THREADS config vars by  
2015-06-24T21:20:22.629350+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v7 created by  
2015-06-24T21:20:22.741201+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-06-24T21:20:36.211995+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 21287 -e production`
2015-06-24T21:20:38.504385+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bin/rails: No such file or directory
2015-06-24T21:20:39.497977+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2015-06-24T21:20:39.506527+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-06-24T21:20:54.735772+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=areyoutaken.herokuapp.com request_id=e476ba5f-9607-4d86-b7e5-d42f84d44252 fwd="73.54.214.248" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-06-24T21:20:55.912874+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=areyoutaken.herokuapp.com request_id=70352214-654e-417e-8d42-82c302bb53eb fwd="73.54.214.248" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-06-24T21:23:31.726199+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=areyoutaken.herokuapp.com request_id=a6cb8ae0-841e-4fc1-ab35-084ac9822e90 fwd="73.54.214.248" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-06-24T21:23:34.015037+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=areyoutaken.herokuapp.com request_id=9b038059-df69-479a-b843-398ec4c4dc8e fwd="73.54.214.248" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Comment: The errors says that `bin/rails` is missing.  Do you have that file checked into your git repository?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a Procfile at the root of your directory? Current heroku dev docs recommend having one to tell heroku how to start your application.

Try including "web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb" in a Procfile.